# Science or technology related resources to learn French

Tags: ressources, apprentissage, science

So, I want to learn French quicker, and I figured that I don't really listen much... I mean, English is easy to learn, you just read it and listen to it all the time through the Internet, TV shows, movies etc. But French? I'm particularly interested in Science Documentaries and Lectures, Cartoons and Technology podcasts. I just need something to listen to while I do other things, to start recognizing the patterns of the language...

Comment: What is your current level ? Are you an absolute beginner or do you already have some bases ?

Comment: Do you have any hobbies ? a particular field of interest ?

Comment: Level: B1. Hobbies: Math, Physics, Piano, Books. Sorry for not mentioning them...

Comment: Well... I guess maths and physics will have technical terms that *might* make it difficult. I tried to watch "Dr House" in English (as I often do with TV shows and movies) and got bored of all the medical terms.

Comment: If you're into maths and physics, I strongly suggest you to study in French books. There are many French books on every topic in maths, for every level : France has a strong tradition in maths. If you like hard puzzles (level undergraduate), you could take a look at exercice books. I can advise you some if you tell me your math level and the topics you're studying.

Comment: I was actually more interested in novels/movies/lectures in France that have to do with those subjects, cause if I study in both French, English and Greek(my mother-language), I'll probably get confused.

Comment: @Antoni4040 Could you edit your question and its title to precise your interests? As is the question is a bit too broad for FL.SE

Comment: If you're interested in other topics as well, fine, but please make it a different question.

Comment: [Canal Académie](http://www.canalacademie.com) is an  Internet radio that has highly academic podcasts (with transcripts) but for subscribers (short extracts available free of charge). They have an agreement with [CAVILAM](http://www.cavilam.com/) that produces [specific podcasts](http://www.canalacademie.com/apprendre/) for learners of French.

Answer (score 2):

Let me at least try to give some pointers (I will append if I find more ideas)...

First, replay TV (some sites might check your geographical origin, but a proxy might fix it).
**Arte** (French-German channel) has [Arte+7](http://arte.tv/guide/fr/plus7) replay with many kinds of documentaries, sometimes related to scientific issues, as well as a recurring one, X:enius revolving around scientific/societal subjects, which you might enjoy.
Also try **France 4** (for documentaries and cartoons, most for kids, some a little more mature) or **France 5** (many documentaries) on [Pluzz](http://pluzz.francetv.fr/).

I also found [**Lapin.org**](http://www.lapin.org/) with comics strips, it has XKCD in French but also other stuff.

You could take a look at "[**FUN**](http://www.france-universite-numerique.fr/moocs.html)" (please don't laugh, it's actually France Université Numérique :-\ ) for some MOOCs, they have many subjects, hopefully you could find some of interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in sciences and have a correct level, I higly recommend [Sur les épaules de Darwin](http://www.franceinter.fr/emission-sur-les-epaules-de-darwin), a weekly science radio broadcast. It is intended for neophytes, so technical vocabulary is always explained. It gets a bit lyrical sometimes which may or may not be an issue, but the speaker has the best voice I know, is always very clear and the broadcasts are always entertaining.

If you are interested in Maths, check out Denis Guedj's books, in the same vein.